# POST is hitting as GET HTTP Request in ASP.net Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, http-post

I have an application which needs to accept the POST request from a client application, but it is accepting it as a GET request with the Exception as "Read Time out..." and "Write time out..." .Tried out the client as Fidler POSt request but the same issue is sustain.
Please help me to resolve this issue.

Do I need to do any IIS or web.config settings is required?

tried out in IIS 7 and 8.5

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication3
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
           protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //var str = Request.QueryString[0];
                       Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
            System.IO.Stream objInputStream = Request.InputStream;
            byte[] arr_bInputBuffer = new byte[objInputStream.Length];
            objInputStream.Read(arr_bInputBuffer, 0, (int)(objInputStream.Length));

            byte[] arr_bOutputBuffer = getByteFromString("Request Executed and length: " + objInputStream.Length + ", Date: " + DateTime.Now);
            Response.OutputStream.Write(arr_bOutputBuffer, 0, arr_bOutputBuffer.Length);
            Request.InputStream.Flush();
            this.Request.InputStream.Close();
        }

            public static byte[] getByteFromString(String strXmlString)
        {
            byte[] arr_bArray;
            try
            {
                arr_bArray = new byte[strXmlString.Length];
                for (int nIndex = 0; nIndex < strXmlString.Length; nIndex++)
                {
                    arr_bArray[nIndex] = System.Convert.ToByte(strXmlString[nIndex]);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw;
            }
            return arr_bArray;
        }


    }
}
```

**Web.Config**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication3-20160611124101.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication3-20160611124101;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>


  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true">
        <!-- block /CFIDE -->
        <!--<denyUrlSequences>
          <add sequence="/CFIDE"/>
        </denyUrlSequences>
        --><!-- block all file extensions except cfm,js,css,html --><!--
        <fileExtensions allowUnlisted="false" applyToWebDAV="true">
          <add fileExtension=".cfm" allowed="true" />
          <add fileExtension=".js" allowed="true" />
          <add fileExtension=".css" allowed="true" />
          <add fileExtension=".html" allowed="true" />
        </fileExtensions>-->
        <!-- hide configuration dir -->
        <!--<hiddenSegments applyToWebDAV="true">-->
          <!--<add segment="configuration" />
        </hiddenSegments>-->
        <!-- limit post size to 10mb, query string to 256 chars, url to 1024 chars -->
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" maxUrl="1073741824" maxQueryString="1073741824">

        </requestLimits>

      <!-- only allow GET,POST verbs -->
        <verbs allowUnlisted="true">
          <add verb="POST" allowed="true" />
          <add verb="GET" allowed="true" />
         <add verb="DEBUG" allowed="true" />

        </verbs>
                <fileExtensions>
                    <remove fileExtension=".cs" />
                    <add fileExtension=".aspx" allowed="true" />
                    <add fileExtension=".cs" allowed="true" />
                </fileExtensions>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpSoap" />
        <add name="HttpPost" />
        <add name="HttpGet" />
        <add name="HttpPostLocalhost" />
        <!-- Documentation enables the documentation/test pages -->
        <add name="Documentation" />
      </protocols>
    </webServices>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />    
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity" />
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <!--
          ASP.NET Membership is disabled in this template. Please visit the following link http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301889 to learn about the ASP.NET Membership support in this template
        -->
        <clear />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
      <providers>
        <!--
          ASP.NET Membership Profile is disabled in this template. Please visit the following link http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301889 to learn about the ASP.NET Membership support in this template
        -->
        <clear />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager>
      <!--
            ASP.NET Membership Role is disabled in this template. Please visit the following link http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301889 to learn about the ASP.NET Membership support in this template
        -->
      <providers>
        <clear />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <!--
            If you are deploying to a cloud environment that has multiple web server instances,
            you should change session state mode from "InProc" to "Custom". In addition,
            change the connection string named "DefaultConnection" to connect to an instance
            of SQL Server (including SQL Azure and SQL  Compact) instead of to SQL Server Express.
      -->
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v12.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Test if it's a postback using the Page.IsPostBack property: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion , but it is not postback .I strongly believe that it could be related to some settings issue .Please help !!!

Comment: I don't think you can access the stream. It is read once and already handled by ASP.NET Forms before you access the stream. To read the form check the values in Request.Form. Take a look here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7579967/retrieving-data-from-a-post-method-in-asp-net